# Display folders and files in android app where stored in Google drive

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I have read so many demos and documentary on above mentioned topic. but here I want something different. If I create a common google drive called A. then someone who having my app he/she should able to read documents and I want to display content in drive A using Text views. 
If you know the answer please can you give me the steps or way to do this.

Thank a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this [Google Drive Android API Demos](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos) that illustrates all possible ways to talk to Drive service with the use of interfaces available in [Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview).

The [`RetrieveContentsActivity.java`](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/RetrieveContentsActivity.java) activity illustrates how to retrieve and read file contents. Then the [`ListFilesInFolderActivity.java`](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/ListFilesInFolderActivity.java) activity illustrates how to list files in a folder.

Also, be noted for the [permission](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions) which grants a user, group, domain or the world access to a file or a folder hierarchy.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

get all the data that  you have saved in  app data  by following the code

```
private void listFiles() {
        Query query =
                new Query.Builder()
                        .addFilter(Filters.or(Filters.eq(SearchableField.MIME_TYPE, "text/html"),
                                Filters.eq(SearchableField.MIME_TYPE, "text/plain")))
                        .build();
        getDriveResourceClient()
                .query(query)

                .addOnSuccessListener(this,

                        new OnSuccessListener<MetadataBuffer>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(MetadataBuffer metadataBuffer) {

                                for (int i = 0; i <metadataBuffer.getCount() ; i++) {
                                    retrieveContents(metadataBuffer.get(i).getDriveId().asDriveFile());
                                }
                            }
                        }

                )
                .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error retrieving files", e);
                        MainActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                });

    }
```

now get all the data that you have saved in google drive by following the code

```
 public void retrieveContents(DriveFile file) {

        Task<DriveContents> openFileTask =
                getDriveResourceClient().openFile(file, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY);



        openFileTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<DriveContents, Task<Void>>() {
            @Override
            public Task<Void> then(@NonNull Task<DriveContents> task) throws Exception {
                DriveContents contents = task.getResult();

                try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(contents.getInputStream()))) {
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        builder.append(line).append("\n");
                    }

                    Log.e("result ", builder.toString());
                }

                Task<Void> discardTask = MainActivity.this.getDriveResourceClient().discardContents(contents);

                return discardTask;
            }
        })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                    }
                });


    }
```